# How to use EnvInject plugin within Job DSL

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl

I believe that the generated config.xml would look something like below:

```
<EnvInjectJobProperty plugin="envinject@1.92.1">
    <info>
        <propertiesContent>
            MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.2.5
            JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/java8
        </propertiesContent>
        <loadFilesFromMaster>false</loadFilesFromMaster>
    </info>
    <on>true</on>
    <keepJenkinsSystemVariables>true</keepJenkinsSystemVariables>
    <keepBuildVariables>true</keepBuildVariables>
    <overrideBuildParameters>false</overrideBuildParameters>
    <contributors/>
</EnvInjectJobProperty>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use EnvInject to configurate `MAVEN_HOME`  and `JAVA_HOME` this should by done by the configuration within the appropriate jobs. either for

```
mavenJob {
  jdk (..)
  mavenInstallation(...)..
}
```

or

```
freestyleJob {
  jdk (..)
}
```